# Sublime Text: how to make shortcut for inserting text?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2, shortcut, sublimetext

I need make a shortcut that will be adding certain text at the cursor, eg {sometext}, how can this be done?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Select the **Key Bindings - User** item under Sublime's **Preferences**, then add the following example line:

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+c"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "hello!"}}
```

This will add a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shortcut to insert the *hello!* snippet.

By the way, don't forget to add a comma to the previous key binding hash so that all but the last line end with a comma. i.e.:

```
[
    {"keys": ["..."], "command": "..." },
    {"keys": ["..."], "command": "..." },
    {"keys": ["..."], "command": "..." },
    {"keys": ["ctrl+shift+c"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "hi!"}}
]
```

Comment: Putting "$0" in the contents will specify the cursor position.
For example, "h$0i!" will place the cursor after the "h" once the snippet is inserted.

Answer (score 12):

If you already have a [snippet file written](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html), say at `Packages/User/myFunction.sublime-snippet`, you can use

**Add this to Preferences > Key Bindings - User**

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+1"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"name": "Packages/User/myFunction.sublime-snippet"} }
```

This example binds the snippet to <kbd>CTRL + 1</kbd>.

I found the info on [Christopher Millward's blog](http://www.millwardesque.com/speed-development-using-keyboard-triggered-snippets-sublime-text-2/).

Answer (score 3):

@skyisred I think the question is already very well answered to the point. But web-developers often will need to generate dummy content to fill the elements. Say "Lorem ipsum".

### Sublime's dummy text generator

Type `lorem` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Sublime will generate the complete Lorem ipsum dummy text for you.

### Creating shortcut keys to do it

If you really want to do it with a shortcut

**Go to**
[On Windows] Preferences > Key Bindings - User 
[On OS X]  Sublime Text > Preferences > Key Bindings - User

```
[
     {"keys": ["ctrl+alt+i","ctrl+alt+s"], "command": "insert_snippet","args": {"contents": "A small snippet"}},
     {"keys": ["ctrl+alt+i","ctrl+alt+m"], "command": "insert_snippet","args": {"contents": "A medium-sized snippet, just good enough to fill in a normal span element."}},
     {"keys": ["ctrl+alt+i","ctrl+alt+l"], "command": "insert_snippet","args": {"contents": "A large snippet, a little more than the medium snippet and just good enough to fill in a paragraph element.This will make your work so much more easier."}}
     ]
```

I have written an article on [creating custom keyboard shortcuts in Sublime Text](http://codezag.com/sublime-text-create-shortcuts-key-bindings/) which might be helpful to you to create shortcuts for other common operations in Sublime Text.

Answer (score 2):

I did something a little bit more complex and complete too. Like \emph{} when you press ctrl+l, ctrl+e ... My job here is to write \textit{} when you press ctrl+shift+i.

Go to Preferences > Browse Packages.
There inside you should save a file named "Text ital.sublime-snippet" for example. Inside of this file put this code:

```
<snippet>
    <description>Italic text</description>
    <content><![CDATA[
\\textit{${1:$SELECTION}}
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <!-- <tabTrigger>hello</tabTrigger> -->
    <scope>text.tex.latex</scope>
</snippet>
```

Then go to Preferences > Key Bindings.
There inside you will write this:

```
[
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+i"],  
    "context":  [
        {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex"}],
    "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"name":"Packages/LaTeXTools/Text ital.sublime-snippet"}}
]
```

Remind that Packages/LaTeXTools/ is the Location of Preferences > Browse Packages.
Remind too that you should insert a comma between two different shortcuts you create.

Hope it works!