# How does $TM_CURRENT_WORD operate in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext

In the Sublime Text documents, I see the following definition for `TM_CURRENT_WORD`

```
$TM_CURRENT_WORD    Current word under the cursor when the snippet was triggered.
```

I'm confused as to how I would use this in practice. Wouldn't the word under the cursor always be the one in the tabTrigger? I'm trying to use this argument to pass in an argument into the Sublime snippet but can't get it to run properly.

Comment: Your confusion is based on the idea, that the only way to insert a snippet is via tab trigger. However they can also be inserted via keybindings or from plugins.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I found this link that allows one to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582210/sublime-text-how-to-make-shortcut-for-inserting-text

Answer (score 0):

This snippet works fine for me:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
Before you insert snippet cursor was in this "$TM_CURRENT_WORD" word.${0}
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>word</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>text</scope>
</snippet>
```

[there](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-do-i-setup-as-a-snippet-tab-trigger/11636) you can find very interesting example:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[ = $TM_CURRENT_WORD + 1]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>++</tabTrigger>
    <description>i = i + 1</description>
    <scope>source.fortran</scope>
</snippet>
```

Comment: You know, I have looked at that link and it seems that the tab trigger was a fluke, as he can't do the same thing with `--` : "The fact that a++ works for you is more by luck than by design, because for some reason sublime sees ++ as a separate "word". But it won't for almost anything else, except in a few other edge cases."

Comment: @Abundance, you can bind shortcut for the snippet instead of using the tab trigger as described in your question comments