# Moving between text and input and textarea areas without using mouse and closing panels

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

In the majority of programs and sites it is possible to switch between input and textarea fields by means of combinations of the <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd> keys.

[image: Stack Overflow Tabs]

But in Sublime Text <kbd>Tab</kbd> — tabulation.

For example, for me open Goto Line Panel and console.

May I move between entry fields and my text also as in the majority of programs becomes by means of keyboard combinations of <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd>? I know, what the <kbd>Tab</kbd> and  <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd> keys is needed for tabulation, but any combination of keys can be used to move between input and textarea fields.

[image: Sublime Text Tabs]

Thanks.

Comment: Sublime is not a web browser. It is a programming editor, where programmers need to unambiguously enter tabs/spaces into their code, including in the console. You can use the `focus_neighboring_group` command to move through separate panes of views.

Comment: @MattDMo, I know the Tab key is needed for tabulation, but any combination of keys can be used to move between input fields. // Command `focus_neighboring_group` works with [**panes**](http://i.imgur.com/rXX4YLW.png), it is not at all what I asked in the question. // Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

TAB will not work but this can be achieved by series of shortcuts:

1. Opening line selector: Ctrl+G
2. Opening search: Ctrl+F
3. Going from search to founded string: Alt+Enter

Shortcuts above are available on Linux version. They may be different on Windows but they are there and can be found in online documentation.

Comment: I will wait for more answers until the bounty period ends. If no better answer is posted I will award the bounty on your answer

Answer (score 0):

With [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) you can personalize your shortcut!

I found [this guide](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/key-bindings) on the official website and this "different but useful" [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582210/sublime-text-how-to-make-shortcut-for-inserting-text) about it.

So you can **create your own sort of switch** with comfortable combination. Example:

- *alt+1* to go to search
- *alt+2* to go to the text
- *alt+3* to go to the bottom
- ...

this is also faster then the "tag way" because it is **not cyclic**!

i haven't tried it but as mentioned by Draco the commands to move exist so you can just make them more comfortable.