# How to assign a string to a keybinding in Sublime Text 4?

Tags: r, sublimetext3, key-bindings, sublimetext4

Is there a way to print something with the given keybinding in `Sublime Text 4`?

E. g. for the sake of `R`, I would like the `alt+oem_minus` and `alt+-` keybindings strokes to result in `<-`.

I understand that for whatever I want to do, I can record a macro and this would work just fine but this action is so trivial that I wonder whether I can do without macro.

I understand that there are probably language plugins and IDEs that include this feature by default, but the most apparent one, the  [`R-IDE`](https://github.com/REditorSupport/sublime-ide-r), doesn't seem to have it, and moreover, `Sublime` is just an editor for quick scripts, not a comprehensive IDE, I have to intention to aggravate the app with scripts I do not need.

Thank you in advance for any response!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sublime Text: how to make shortcut for inserting text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582210/sublime-text-how-to-make-shortcut-for-inserting-text)

Comment: Yes, it does. I apologise for insufficient googling, that answer didn't emerge among search results or similar questions. Shall I, therefore, delete my question, or may it remain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Sublime Text, go to `Preferences` > `Key Bindings` and add this:

```json
[
    {
        "keys": ["alt+keypad_minus", "alt+-"],
        "command": "insert_snippet",
        "args": {"contents": "<-"}
    }
]
```

If you want to position the cursor after `<-`, you can do it via `$0` like this:

```json
"args": {"contents": "<- $0"}
```

Comment: Writing several keys in a row doesn't work for me on `Sublime Text 4`, but writing a single key does.